# Problems with starting the tor service on Windows 10 (Error 1064)

Tags: configuration, windows

Goal: start the tor service on Windows 10 with specified `torrc`.

My attempt:

**1 step.**
`tor --service install -options -f C:\TorBrowser\torrc`

**2 step.** Trying to start the service... I get the error.

[image: Error 1064]

---

`torrc` file located in `C:\TorBrowser\torrc`:

```
Bridge <<SOME VALUE>>
Bridge <<SOME VALUE>>
Bridge <<SOME VALUE>>
DataDirectory C:\TorBrowser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor
ExcludeExitNodes <<SOME VALUE>>,{??}
GeoIPFile C:\TorBrowser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\TorBrowser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6
Log notice file TorBrowser/Tor/notice.log
SocksPolicy accept private:*,reject *:*
SocksPort 9051 CacheDNS UseDNSCache
StrictNodes 1
TrackHostExits <<SOME VALUE>>
UseBridges 1
```

Where `<<SOME VALUE>>` is some value :)

When I use Tor Browser with that `torrc` file — all OK.

When I try to run `C:\TorBrowser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor>tor.exe -f C:\TorBrowser\torrc` the process `tor.exe` starts and dies in ~one second.(I looked in the Task Manager.)

---

The similar Tor [ticket](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/17145).

> The only way to create a running tor service for a relay is to use the
>   "sc create..." in cmd command line as irc#tor suggested. So
>   this is how it works:
>   `sc create "Tor Win32 Service" binPath= "\"C:\tornou\Tor\tor.exe\" --nt-service -f \"C:/tornou/Data/Tor/torrc\""`

I tried this solution. The problem remains, the service does not start (with Error 1064).

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Are the permissions set appropriately? and the `Log file notice ...` line provides a relative path, do you know which directory it will be relative to when the Tor service starts?

Comment: Also can you please include any output from the log file? (with bridge addresses redacted, of course)

Comment: @canonizingironize What permissions do you have in mind? "do you know which directory" – `C:\TorBrowser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\notice.log`. [Log example](https://pastebin.com/2GB3Df7K) (I started the browser, launched a couple of applications, closed the browser. Attempts to start the service do not leave anything in the log file.)

Comment: Try making the Log file a non-relative path. The command line will produce no output on Windows because cmd.exe doesn't handle it. It's likely reporting some error that you cannot see.

Comment: @canonizingironize You are a wizard! Many thanks! :) 
P.S. Post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log line is a relative path, within Tor Browser this normally works because it is careful about the directory it is in when it interprets the relative path.

```
Log notice file TorBrowser/Tor/notice.log
```

You should instead make it an absolute path instead to ensure it's opened in the correct location. e.g.:

```
Log notice file C:\TorBrowser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\notice.log
```

Comment: I also had problems with paths because I used UNIX-style path separators on my Windows machine. `--verify-config` yelled at me what the paths provided were relative when they were not, because they explicitly started with the drive letter and root directory specification. Converting the separators to Windows-style ones fixed this error for me.